# accessing data from a dynamically added custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, dynamic-controls

I am writing a survey generating system in asp.net.  i asked an ealier question about the best way to create controls that can be passed about as variables.  This was problematic with user controls so i was advised to use custom controls and  a quick way to do this was to inherit from the panel control and just add a bunch of standard controls the the controls collection by overriding the CreateChildControls method.  This way i could create my "survey" controls,which are basically Questions in the survey.  THe question controls are then dynamically added to the page.  This all works well but know i have come to the point that i want to try and retrieve the values from these controls and i seem to be lost in a nether world of of viewstates and page lifecycles.  I can ensure that the dynamically added text boxes have a known ID, however  even if i add the parent control in the page init handler the CreateChildControls method does not run until after until after the viewstate is loaded. I cannot work out how to retreive the values from these text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the EnsureChildControls method on the init handler of your control to ensure CreateChildControls is called before the ViewState is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly seem to be doing this the hard way.  TextBox values are not saved in the Viewstate, they are posted in the request.

Why aren't you using a UserControl here?  So you can "pass" it somewhere?  what exactly are you trying to do?